# Essential features of a function

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

In calculus when we look at $x=g(t), y=h(t)$ we first ask if this is a function $y=f(x)$. Then we look at properties like :

What is the domain of X and Y?
 - Is it continuous, monotonic, smooth, analytic?
 - Asymptotic behavior, special points like poles (e.i. $0$ for $y=1/x$)
 - Cusps
 - What is the domain of the Tailor series expansion?
 - The norm and its implications for Fourier analysis

Let's assume I have a new probabilistic function that I want to study. It is nice in the sense of continuity and smoothness, but I don't have an analytic solution for it.

I can compute f(x) for a given x in seconds. What should I study to make it a well-defined function?

---

This function arises from some probability distribution. So, the integral over the domain of X is exactly 1. I use "well defined" in a broad sense: "I have a recipe to compute f(x) and the value stays the same". Here is my question. What should I study to characterize this function?

Comment: By probabilistic function, do you mean CDF, PDF, characteristic function, or what? When you say "well-defined", do you mean how to verify a function qualifies as "a probabilistic function"?

Comment: @J.G. This is PFD. My function is somewhat exotic and I haven't seen it in literature.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the PDF & how you got it.

Comment: @J.G. I would love to, but this is an unpublished result... Can you please point me to some literature on the analysis of PFD?

Comment: I still don't know what you want. You've proven a distribution has a PDF you can describe in one way, but you either want to describe it another way or prove a property of it you haven't already proven. Until you can be more detailed than that, there's little we can do.